# How do I sign an xlsm file with an Azure KeyVault stored certificate after June 2023?

Tags: excel, digital-signature, azure-keyvault

Other similar posts suggest using AzureSignTool, however, AzureSignTool does not accept xlsm as a valid file type.

Previously we used the windows sign tool, however, new certificates are not exportable and so we cannot use this method anymore.

Our signing is done as part of a CI/CD pipeline in DevOps, so we would like to avoid having to manually sign the VBA using a fips device or yubikey if possible.

Tried using AzureSignTool but it says xlsm is an unsupported file type.

Signing a digest file is not enough as excel security settings will reject any macros that aren't signed.

Can't use the exported certificate with signtool as it does not include the private key.

Comment: signtool.exe doesn't require the certificate/key to be present as key. It also supports using it from Windows user certificate store. See example command `SignTool sign /n "My Company Publisher" MyControl.exe` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/using-signtool-to-sign-a-file

Answer (score 1):

While it's best to leave the private key in Key Vault - and you can't export it from a Managed HSM at all, by design - you may be able to download the certificate key pair if you have the `secret/get` permission as well.

I added a [DownloadCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.certificates.certificateclient.downloadcertificateasync) method to the Azure SDK's `CertificateClient` or, if you're stuck using older versions, you can see the previous sample code: https://learn.microsoft.com/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-net/get-certificate-private-key/

Alternatively, have you tried the [Azure code signing task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.AzureCodeSigning) for Azure Pipelines or [for GitHub Actions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-code-signing-action)?

If they don't support *.xlsm*, it's possible the hosted agents don't have the necessary Authenticode providers installed. SignTool and AzureSignTool both rely on Authenticode APIs which rely on providers. Many are built into Windows, but perhaps Office ones aren't. You might file a bug against the agent providers then e.g., Microsoft or GitHub for hosted agents.

Office may not install a SIP, either. Using the sample program below and checking against a .xlsx file I have laying around, I get -2146762749 or `TRUST_E_SUBJECT_FORM_UNKNOWN` meaning the SIP isn't known.

```cpp
#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")

#define UNICODE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mssip.h>

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "sipchk.exe <filename>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    GUID pgSubject = {};
    if (!CryptSIPRetrieveSubjectGuid(argv[1], nullptr, &pgSubject))
    {
        auto err = GetLastError();
        fwprintf(stderr, L"failed to check %ls: %d\n", argv[1], err);
        return err;
    }

    SIP_DISPATCH_INFO sip = { sizeof(SIP_DISPATCH_INFO) };
    if (!CryptSIPLoad(&pgSubject, 0, &sip))
    {
        auto err = GetLastError();
        fwprintf(stderr, L"failed to load SIP for %ls: %d\n", argv[1], err);
        return err;
    }

    HMODULE hMod = 0;
    if (!GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS | GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT, (LPCWSTR)sip.pfGet, &hMod))
    {
        auto err = GetLastError();
        fwprintf(stderr, L"failed to get SIP module for %ls: %d\n", argv[1], err);
        return err;
    }

    wchar_t wzPath[MAX_PATH];
    if (!GetModuleFileName(hMod, wzPath, MAX_PATH))
    {
        auto err = GetLastError();
        fwprintf(stderr, L"failed to get SIP module filename for %ls: %d\n", argv[1], err);
        return err;
    }

    wprintf(L"%ls would be processed by SIP %ls\n", argv[1], wzPath);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your great "sipchk.exe"! After installing the [Office SIPs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56617), this actually works for me: `.\sipchk.exe D:\signtest.xlsm
D:\signtest.xlsm would be processed by SIP C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll`. Please note that it is crucial to use an x86 build (no  x64 build) of `sipchk.exe`, because the Office SIPs are 32bit only.